# Scrollable left column w/ 100% remaining screen height, scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a scrollable left column that takes up 100% of the remaining space, minus the distance from the top of the page.  It works well currently, but there's a few issues.  When I initially created it, I ran into an infinite scrolling issue because I wasn't taking into account the footer height:

http://jsfiddle.net/sUqtD/5/

If I subtract the height of the footer:

http://jsfiddle.net/sUqtD/4/

it works to an extent, but if I resize the browser height, and the right column height pushes the footer down, the left column height still takes into account the footer height.

So my question, how can I get the left column to take up 100% remaining height in all conditions?

Comment: Are you allowed to use `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/mXjLE/1/

Its not code perfect, but it works (I things).

Comment: Note:
If you want left column 100% height over footer or header margin you must use postion:absolute (or fixed) for left-column and another solutin.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just using absolute positioning on the left column and was able to fix my issue.  Your comment triggered it in my head, so marking your answer as accepted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You only had some minor errors. The example you made where you subtracted the footer was close but you stil need to configurate your CSS as well..

Take a look at the code I made.. It works and takes the footer into account even if you decide to change it.. (  it is only a minor rewrite of your code.)

Hope it helps http://jsfiddle.net/sUqtD/20/

**EDIT** 
There is a error when the window size is smaller than the left column - but I'll solve this asap :)